# Different homepage for logged and logged-out users

Tags: php, session, authentication, seo

I use PHP for my project and need to display different pages for users who logged in and those who are not. One solution is to check if session is set `if(isset($_SESSION['id']))` and if it is, *include* the one page, and if not, *include* another.

Example: index.php

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }

    if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
        include 'logged_home.php';
    else
        include 'unlogged_home.php'; 
?>
```

But I think it's a bad SEO technique since the index file doesn't have any metadata, title, and keywords. I don't think Google would crawl to **unlogged_home.php** and get all the keywords from there.

What is the best solution to display different content in index.php based on whether the session is set or not?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include is not a redirect. As far as Google is concerned, you are only serving up one file - index.php.

Comment: So it's OK to use this technique SEO-wise?

Comment: @Noob: there's tons of sites that have different home pages for logged-in v.s. not-logged-in users. If google penalized everyone for this technique, then a huge chunk of the web wouldn't be getting indexed. e.g. this site is one of them.

Comment: I don't see why not. You could build your site one word at a time with each word in a different file and then include them all and Google(or any other search engines) would only see the final result in index.php. All of this processing happens on the server before anyone - spider or user - gets the finished product.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes perfect sense.